# Treating strings for insertion into XElement

Tags: c#, string, xelement

We gather lots of strings and send them to our clients in xml fragments. These strings could contain literally any character. We've been seeing an error caused by trying to serialize XElement instances that contain "bad" characters. Here's an example:

```
var message = new XElement("song");
char c = (char)0x1a; //sub
var someData = string.Format("some{0}stuff", c);
var attr = new XAttribute("someAttr", someData);
message.Add(attr);
string msgStr = message.ToString(SaveOptions.DisableFormatting); //exception here
```

The code above generates an exception at the indicated line. Here's the stacktrace:

```
'SUB', hexadecimal value 0x1A, is an invalid character. System.ArgumentException System.ArgumentException: '', hexadecimal value 0x1A, is an invalid character.
   at System.Xml.XmlEncodedRawTextWriter.InvalidXmlChar(Int32 ch, Char* pDst, Boolean entitize)
   at System.Xml.XmlEncodedRawTextWriter.WriteAttributeTextBlock(Char* pSrc, Char* pSrcEnd)
   at System.Xml.XmlEncodedRawTextWriter.WriteString(String text)
   at System.Xml.XmlWellFormedWriter.WriteString(String text)
   at System.Xml.XmlWriter.WriteAttributeString(String prefix, String localName, String ns, String value)
   at System.Xml.Linq.ElementWriter.WriteStartElement(XElement e)
   at System.Xml.Linq.ElementWriter.WriteElement(XElement e)
   at System.Xml.Linq.XElement.WriteTo(XmlWriter writer)
   at System.Xml.Linq.XNode.GetXmlString(SaveOptions o)
```

My suspicion is that this is not the correct behaviour and the bad char should be escaped into the XML. Whether this is desirable or not is a question I will answer later.

So here's the question:

Is there some way of treating strings such that this error might not occur, or should I simply strip all chars below char `0x20` and cross my fingers?

Comment: Good question. Actually you shouldn't strip *all* chars below 0x20, because some of them are properly escaped (e.g. CR, LF, TAB...). But I can't see any reason why the others are not escaped...

Comment: Will your clients ever actually need those characters in the strings?

Comment: No. Definitely not. They're either rendered to a WPF textbox or as an mvcstring in a webapp. In fact, in our case, even @ThomasLevesque 's cr/lf/tab combos could be stripped because we're expecting a single line. These strings make quite a journey to our servers via idv3 tags, broadcasting software and shoutcast servers. It's quite possible that encodings have been mangled along the way. I'm thinking my fix is entirely applicable for us. I'm still confused by this exception, and would like confirmation that I appear to have spotted a bug in .net.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is what I am using in my code:

```
    static Lazy<Regex> ControlChars = new Lazy<Regex>(() => new Regex("[\x00-\x1f]", RegexOptions.Compiled));

    private static string FixData_Replace(Match match)
    {
        if ((match.Value.Equals("\t")) || (match.Value.Equals("\n")) || (match.Value.Equals("\r")))
            return match.Value;

        return "&#" + ((int)match.Value[0]).ToString("X4") + ";";
    }

    public static string Fix(object data, MatchEvaluator replacer = null)
    {
        if (data == null) return null;
        string fixed_data;
        if (replacer != null) fixed_data = ControlChars.Value.Replace(data.ToString(), replacer);
        else fixed_data = ControlChars.Value.Replace(data.ToString(), FixData_Replace);
        return fixed_data;
    }
```

All characters bellow 0x20 (except \r \n \t)are replaced by their XML unicode codes: 0x1f => "&#001f".
Xml parser should automatically unescape it back to 0x1f when reading file.
Just use new XAttribute("attribute", Fix(yourString))

It works for XElement content a it should probably also work for XAttributes.

Comment: Fixed with something similar. For lack of a more compelling answer, I'll give you the points.

Answer (score 9):

A little digging with ILSpy revealed that one can use the XmlWriter/ReaderSettings.CheckCharacters field to control whether or not an exception is thrown for invalid characters. Borrowing from the XNode.ToString method and the XDocument.Parse method, I've come up with the following examples:

To stringify an XLinq object with invalid (control) characters:

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse("<root>foo</root>");
using (StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter())
{
    XmlWriterSettings xmlWriterSettings = new XmlWriterSettings { OmitXmlDeclaration = true, CheckCharacters = false };
    using (XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(stringWriter, xmlWriterSettings))
    {
        xdoc.WriteTo(xmlWriter);
    }

    return stringWriter.ToString();
}
```

To parse an XLinq object with invalid characters:

```
XDocument xdoc;
using (StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(text))
{
    XmlReaderSettings xmlReaderSettings = new XmlReaderSettings { CheckCharacters = false, DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Parse, MaxCharactersFromEntities = 10000000L, XmlResolver = null };
    using (XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(stringReader, xmlReaderSettings))
    {
        xdoc = XDocument.Load(xmlReader);
    }
}
```